# trouble changing request headers in Firefox with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firefox, post, http-headers, content-type

My backend requires the 'Content-Type' request header to be exactly 'application/json'. This is a CORS request and everything works fine in Chrome. The exact header, from developer tools network tab source:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I set this in AngularJS with $http.default.headers.post and it works fine in Chrome. However it doesn't work in Firefox. Firefox sends this instead:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I tried to change headers by:

- settings $http.default.headers (for .post, .common)
- setting custom headers for one request
- using an $http interceptor

All of those methods work well in Chrome, but not in Firefox. **The request contains data**.

If I remove the 'Content-Type' header all together, it still is sent, but then it is:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

(this happens in both Chrome and Firefox).

This leads me to think that the browser forces the header :)
How can I circumvent this in Firefox?

Comment: Incoming dumb question from me: Can't you just make your backend accept what is a perfectly normal HTTP header? You never know when/if Chrome suddenly decides to start enforcing it too.

Comment: the backend isn't acutally mine - I am using LimeSurvey RemoteControl API, which is a bit too sensitive.
I can transform the request in the webserver - which I did just now, which kind of solves the problem, but not the question.

Comment: Yeah, I left that as a comment and not an answer for that very reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox has `charset=UTF-8` [hard-coded for string payloads](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/6ee5583b0fa6/content/base/src/nsXMLHttpRequest.cpp#l2438).

You may however send a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", ...);
r.send(new Blob(
 [JSON.stringify({a:1})],
 {type:"application/json"}
));
```

This also works perfectly fine with the angular `$http` XHR wrapper:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: new Blob([JSON.stringify({
        a: 1
    })])
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FV8uj/2/)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I don't want to send it as a Blob, as it seems I won't be able to leverage AngularJS that way.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the hard-coding. Driving me crazy :)