# Angular resource HTTP requests sent with "accept: text/html" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, django-rest-framework, angular-resource

Resource output is fine with Chrome but with FF data object looks weird, there's an array with some html, each symbol is distinct element there.

Here's a factory I have:

```
MyApp.factory('MyObj', 
    ['$resource', '$http', '$rootScope',
    function($resource, $http, $rootScope){
        return $resource('/api/objects/:id');
}]);
```

And that's how I use it inside controller:

```
MyApp.get(function(data) {
    $scope.objects = data['objects'];
});
```

For some reason, request to the API is sent with HTTP header:

```
Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
```

So there's a response header:

```
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

I tried to do

```
MetronicApp.config(function($resourceProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
});
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Not enough info given?

Comment: Wrong http headers along with the request, can't figure out why and why it's happening only with FF.

Comment: Possible duplicateof : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465304/trouble-changing-request-headers-in-firefox-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to remove `rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer` from DRF `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES`. It's not the best solution though, I'd like to have that browsable API.